# how to configure action with * in it?

Tags: struts

```
<action path="/edit*" type="org.apache.struts.weapp.example.Edit{1}Action" name="{1}Form" scope="request">
       <forward name="failure" path="/mainmenu.jsp"/>
       <forward name="success" path="/{1}.jsp"/>
</action>
```

Referring to the above how does the developer change the following sample to accept the request of format: /edit*Customer?id=125?

```
•The developer changes validate="false" to validate="edit".
•The developer changes path="/edit*" to actionPath="/edit*".
•The developer changes path="/edit*" to path="/edit\**".
•The developer changes path="/edit*" to path="/(edit)\***".
•The developer changes validate="false" to validate="wildcard
```